# Insert Signatures (Images) into an Infopath Forms

Tags: 2010, infopath

I need to insert Signatures (Images) into an InfoPath web forms. I also need a drop down menu in the form so that a when a person is selected & his respective signature shows up in the form.

Is it possible to do it?

Any article or blog post would be of great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a drop down control to your form
- Add a section to your form for every entry in your drop down list
- Upload an image of the signature to each section
- Set a formatting rule on every section that says:

IF: dropdown IS NOT EQUAL TO *value** 
 THEN: Hide this control

*value* is then the value of the entry in your drop down list.